# Performance issue running a simulator with 1/2 million queries. What is the best solution?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark, cluster-computing, databricks

I am writing a Simulator, written in Python. I won't go into the details of the simulator, but essentially I have a list of timestamped items (e.g. 100000). Each item get's processed in a model, performing various calculations. Within that model I need to make around 15-20 SQL queries. Some are fairly complex. The range of time for each query ranges from 0.001s to 0.2s. The database is optimised with indexing and I think I've squeezed out optimal performance on each query.

The issue I am having is that the simulator takes well over 24 hours. I've tried many different ways to deal with this, e.g. threading, multiprocesing, asynchronous routines etc.. The asynchronous/multiprocessing approach's yielded best results (only marginally) but the CPU would max out (no good if I have other processes running on that machine).

So I am now in a position where I am taking stock and thinking that this is actually an infrastructure problem. I **think** the best way to deal with this is to utilise some kind of distributed cluster.

From reading around, I think using Spark (PySpark) might be the best way, so that each item in that list has a job that is parallelized on different nodes in a cluster.

Spark seems very complicated though so I think I need to outsource this so it's out the box by using Databricks or something like that.

I haven't got any GCP, AWS or Azure database so will need to get it.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is going the Databricks/Spark route the right way to solve the issue outlined?
2. By running potentially 1/2 million queries for a simulation do I run the risk of a bill being insane (e.g. 1000+ USD on any of those main cloud providers)?

You might think, *Why don't you just query the data once, get the result set and work from there...*

It is because sometimes I will only need to process 1 item, depends on the **mode** of the application plus other niche data features, so getting all data in python memory and running from there is very inefficient.

Comment: I'm not sure what answer you expect, since you haven't said anything specific about the types of calculations you need to do. I think you already know that your options are to spend a bunch of money to run the task with greater parallelism, or else change your model to reduce the calculation work per item.

Comment: It is mostly aggregate functions within SQL, extracting result sets into nested dictionaries. The python part of each task/item is very simple and quick. It's the querying multiple times an item that is the issue.

Comment: Show us some of the queries.  By "optimised with indexing", does that include "composite" and "covering" where appropriate?  How many gigabytes of data?